# Update MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little script which allows me to update my MySQL Database.
It first shows me all entries of my table, and puts it in a form.
Then It should update all the changes back to the database.
But unfortunately the script doesn't work.
Can anyone please help me?

This is the file: updateform.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> 
<style type="text/css">  

body { 
    margin:50px 0px; padding:0px; 
    text-align:center; 
        font:13px Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif 
    } 

#content { 
    width:1000px; 
    margin:0px auto; 
    text-align:left; 
    padding:15px; 
    border:1px dashed #333; 
    background-color:#eee; 
    } 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id='content'><h3><center>Update Information</center></h3> 
<?php 
// connect to the database 
mysql_connect(host,dbuser,passwd); 

// select the database 
mysql_select_db(db) or die("Unable to select database"); 

// run the query and put the results in an array variable called $result 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM program ORDER BY 'id'"); 
// find out how many records there are to update 
$size = count($_POST['id']); 

// start a counter in order to number the input fields for each record 
$i = 0; 
print "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0'><tr><td>"; 
// open a form 
print "<form name='id' method='post' action='update.php'> 
<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1'><tr> 

<td align='center'><strong>ID</strong></td> 
<td align='center'><strong>Vorname</strong></td> 
<td align='center'><strong>Nachname</strong></td> 
<td align='center'><strong>Punkte</strong></td> 
</tr>\n"; 

// start a loop to print all of the courses with their book information 
// the mysql_fetch_array function puts each record into an array. each time it is called, it moves the array counter up until there are no more records left 
while ($Update = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  print "<tr>\n"; 
// assuming you have three important columns (the index (id), the course name (course), and the book info (bookinfo)) 
  // start displaying the info; the most important part is to make the name an array (notice bookinfo[$i]) 
  print "<td align='center'><p>{$Update['id']}</p></td>\n"; 

  print "<td align='center'><input type='text' size='40' name='vorname[$i]' value='{$Update['vorname']}' /></td>\n"; 

  print "<td align='center'><input type='text' size='40' name='nachname[$i]' value='{$Update['nachname']}' /></td>\n"; 

  print "<td align='center'><input type='text' size='40' name='punkte[$i]' value='{$Update['punkte']}' /></td>\n"; 

  print "</tr>\n"; 

// add 1 to the count, close the loop, close the form, and the mysql connection 
++$i; 
} 
print "<tr> 
<td colspan='4' align='center'><input type='submit' value='submit' />"; 
print "</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</form> 
</table>"; 
mysql_close(); 
?><br /><br /><div></body> 
</html>
```

this is the file: update.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head> 
<style type="text/css">  

body { 
    margin:50px 0px; padding:0px; 
    text-align:center; 
        font:13px Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif 
    } 

#content { 
    width:1000px; 
    margin:0px auto; 
    text-align:left; 
    padding:15px; 
    border:1px dashed #333; 
    background-color:#eee; 
    } 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id='content'><h3><center>Success! </center></h3> 
<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='0'><tr><td> 


<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1'> 
<tr> 

<td align='center'><strong>Vorname</strong></td> 
<td align='center'><strong>Nachname</strong></td> 
<td align='center'><strong>Punkte</strong></td> 
<td align='center'><strong>ID</strong></td> 
</tr> 
<?php 
// connect to the database and select the correct database 
mysql_connect(host,dbuser,passwd); 
mysql_select_db(db) or die("Unable to select database"); 

// find out how many records there are to update 
$size = count($_POST['id']); 

// start a loop in order to update each record 
$i = 0; 
while ($i < $size) { 
// define each variable 
$vorname = $_POST['vorname'][$i]; 
$nachname = $_POST['nachname'][$i]; 
$punkte = $_POST['punkte'][$i]; 
$id = $_POST['id'][$i]; 

// do the update and print out some info just to provide some visual feedback 

$query = "UPDATE `program` SET `vorname` = '$vorname', `nachname` = '$nachname', `punkte` = '$punkte' WHERE `id` = '$id' LIMIT 1"; 
mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query"); 
print " 

</tr> 
<td align='left'><p>$vorname</p></td> 
<td align='left'>$nachname</td> 
<td align='left'>$punkte</td> 
<td align='left'>$id</td> 
</tr> 
"; 
++$i; 
} 
mysql_close(); 
?> 
<tr> 
<td colspan='4' align='center'> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</td> 
</tr> 

</table></div></body></html>
```

Please can anyone help me?
Greets Alex

Comment: What seems to go wrong? Do you get errors?

Comment: Look into using mysqli_* functions as mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot that.. :D
No. Everything goes right. I can see all data from the database. But when I "submit", I can only see "Sucess" as headline and below, there are the headlines of the colums of the Database. (Vorname,Nachname,Punkte,ID) And if i check the database, nothing changed.

Comment: I don't see an input for the id in your form

Comment: no the ID shouldn't be changed. Only "Vorname", "Nachname" and "Punkte"

Comment: but you need a $_POST['id'][$i] to change the correct record

Comment: but there is a $_POST['id'][$i]; in row 28 from the bottom up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
print "<td align='center'><p>{$Update['id']}</p></td>\n";
```

To

```
print "<td align='center'>
   <p>{$Update['id']}</p>
   <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id[$i]\" value=\"{$Update['id']}\" />
</td>\n";
```

Comment: tried it.
An Error occurs..

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /../../../../updateform.php on line 56

which is this line:
<input type="hidden" name="id[$i]" value="{$Update['id']}" />

Comment: sorry about that i forgot to add \ before the ". Take a look at my edited answer

Comment: well it seems this error is fixed, but it created a new one..  
  
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRINT in /../../../../updateform.php on line 60  
  
which is this line:

  print "<td align='center'><input type='text' size='40' name='vorname[$i]' value='{$Update['vorname']}' /></td>\n";

Comment: you can replace quotes (") with apostrophes (') when printing out html with PHP to avoid using backslashes.

Comment: how is it possible to add a button next to every line which allows you to delete the whole entry..?

Comment: It does not need to be button. You can add a link tag that will point to the delete page and you can style it to look like a button. Example: `<a href="delete.php?id=123">Del</a>` or you can work out something like this: `<a href="delete.php?id=123"><button>Del</button></a>`

Comment: but how do I make sure the right ID is selected?
do I have to set up a new file "delete.php"??
isn't it possible to add it to this one?

Comment: It is possible to add it to the same file but it is good to separate your functionality in different structures, in your case files. You will need to set the links id param dynamically while you are iterating through the items. In your delete you should make some validations for the id-check if it is a number, test if the current user can delete this item etc.

Comment: i made two files.
deleteuser.php and delete.php

in deleteuser.php i made oke Input field where I input the ID of the user and submit it with a button which opens the delete.php;  

and in delete.php i say:  
$query1 = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = '$id' ";  
and then..  
$query2="DELETE FROM table WHERE id = '$id'";   
and then print.. deleted...  
this can be used for the other form as well or?

Comment: Yes, you can create something similar to that. Just one suggestion - escape your database parameters or you could get sql injected.

Comment: can anyone do something with just knowing my table's name and some file's names?
or have i forgotten something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not properly tracking the IDs of your records.

Try naming the form text inputs according to the ID.

For example :

```
print "<td align='center'><input type='text' size='40' name='vorname_".$Update['id']."' value='".$Update['vorname']."' /></td>\n";
```

You can strip the id afterwards with explode, strval or a regex function.